# Locating color code for template menu buttons?

Tags: html, css, templates, menu, colors

I am fairly new to HTML/CSS but I think I am getting a basic hang of things. I understand more and more but need a little assistance with a template I am playing around with.

The template is Dragonfruit from TemplateTemo and can been seen here: http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_411_dragonfruit

I've been playing around in the HTML and CSS files but I cannot find the code for changing the two colours on the top menu bar buttons. (The two colours on the Home, About etc. buttons)

I would really appriciate if someone could take two minutes and download the template files and tell me where to look or how things work.

Any help is surely welcome!

Thanks a lot,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

You need too inspect the template.

The menu uses a background image:

```
.glossymenu {
    background: url("/images/menub_bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 46px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 34px;
    position: relative;
}
```

On the menu hover you have a image too:

```
.glossymenu li a:hover, .glossymenu li.current a {
    background: url("/images/menub_hover_left.gif") no-repeat scroll left center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #fff;
}
```

The header use a background image too:

```
#top_section {
    background: url("/images/templatemo-header-6.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 116px;
}
```

You can change  the rule background to colors:

```
background: #cccccc;
```

Comment: Hey Luis,

Thank you so much for the answer but I am not sure I completely understand it. In what files exactly do you locate the .glossymenu codes you are referring to? The images in the codes (menub_hover_left.gif etc.) are also not in the images folder.

Kind regards,

Brian

Comment: This template (images, html,css) are in the remote server. You must have the template locally or access remotely to the server to play with the files.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks again! I'm still not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you mean that I have to download the template files locally I have done this. However I still cannot find the menu code you are referring to in your first answer.

Are you saying they are located in a seperate online location different from the template site? If so, where do you locate the URL to access the source code from your first answer?

I apologize for my lack of understanding, as stated I am still fairly new when it comes to this. :-)

Comment: Your css file is in the root off the template - tm_style.min.css . The images are inside the directory images